# Why can't I reference a nested object using `val` or `typealias` that refers to an object?

Tags: reference, kotlin, inner-classes

Consider the following code:

```
object SomeObjectA {
    object SomeObjectB {
        val a = "test"
    }
}

val X = SomeObjectA
typealias Y = SomeObjectA

SomeObjectA.SomeObjectB // works
X.SomeObjectB // error
Y.SomeObjectB // error
```

I can't use `val` or `typealias`, which reference the outer object, to refer to a nested object within that outer object. Why?

Comment: Similar issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12632

Comment: Just encountered same thing to the `Y.SomeObjectB`, reported as [KT-24902](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24902), since other issues are similar, but not really the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the compiler error is comes from java, and the kotlin `object`s convert to java `class`es as below:

```
public final class SomeObjectA {
    private SomeObjectA() {/**/}

    public static final SomeObjectA INSTANCE = new SomeObjectA();

    public static final class SomeObjectB {
        private SomeObjectB() {/**/}

        public static final SomeObjectB INSTANCE = new SomeObjectB();
    }
}
```

`SomeObjectA.SomeObjectB` is compiled to java code as below:

```
SomeObjectA.SomeObjectB.INSTANCE;
```

`SomeObjectA` is compiled to java code as below:

```
SomeObjectA.INSTANCE
```

we know kotlin is base on java, and java don't allow access the nested classes via instance reference, if you do the compiler will reports an error:"**Error: java: unexpected type required: class,package found: variable**", for example:

```
SomeObjectA a = SomeObjectA.INSTANCE;
SomeObjectB b = a.SomeObjectB.INSTANCE;// error 
             // ^--- compiler don't know where to go? package&class or variable?
```

the code below, kotlin compiler will transforms the java compiler error as: "**Error: Kotlin: Nested object 'SomeObjectB' accessed via instance reference**".

```
val a = SomeObjectA;
val b = a.SomeObjectB;
//        ^--- Error
```

> Type aliases do not introduce new types. They are equivalent to the corresponding underlying types.

so the two statements below are equality:

```
 val a = SomeObjectA;
 typealias a2 = SomeObjectA;
```

avoiding to the use of `typealias` causing unnecessary compiler error, kotlin doesn't include all nested classes in `typealias`.

Answer (score 6):

What you described happens because `SomeObjectA` in your example is simultaneously a name of an object *and* the name of its class.

So to access `SomeObjectB`, you need to use the `<classname>.<classname>` syntax. That is why `X.SomeObjectB` doesn't compile (`<object>.<classname>` is unsupported)

P.S. This doesn't really explain your second problem with `typealias`. It looks like like a bug to me, but I'm not sure.